# Django Database query optimization on filter() same QuerySet and assigning to different variables

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a base `queryset` and the goal is to build a dashboard statistic using the base `queryset` but filtered by different values for each variable.

My simplified code for better understanding:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    """ Invoice model.
     Represents a basic income/outcome transaction. """
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name="transactions", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name="Title")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="transactions", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    operation = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=OPERATION_TYPE, verbose_name="operation")
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="value")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True) 

class Category(MPTTModel):
    """ Category model. 
    Represents a category where money have been spent/earned."""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=54, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
```

Having the models above I've created `ClassBasedView(ListView)` :

```
class DashboardView(ListView):
    """ View implements dashboard functionality. """
    model = Transaction
    template_name = "invoices/dashboard.html"
    ordering = "-date_created"


    def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet[Any]:
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.filter(user=self.request.user).select_related("category__parent")
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs: Any) -> dict[str, Any]:
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # retrieving all transactons
        transactions_all = self.get_queryset()

        # retrieving incomes/expenses summary for current month
        incomes_this_month = transactions_all.filter(transaction_filter.transaction_date_filter(month="current"), operation="incomes")
        incomes_this_month_sum = incomes_this_month.aggregate(Sum("value")).get("value__sum")
        
        expenses_this_month = transactions_all.filter(transaction_filter.transaction_date_filter(month="current"), operation="expenses")                          
        expenses_this_month_sum = expenses_this_month.aggregate(Sum("value")).get("value__sum")
        
        # retrieving incomes/expenses summary for previous month
        transactions_prev_month = transactions_all.filter(transaction_filter.transaction_date_filter(month="previous"))
   
        incomes_previous_month = transactions_prev_month.filter(operation="incomes")
        incomes_previous_month_sum = incomes_previous_month.aggregate(Sum("value")).get("value__sum")

        expenses_previous_month = transactions_prev_month.filter(operation="expenses")
        expenses_previous_month_sum = expenses_previous_month.aggregate(Sum("value")).get("value__sum")
```

**You can see `transaction_date_filter` in `filter()` manager. It's just a `Q()` objects for date filtering.**

Using `select_related` I managed to remove duplicates but there are still "similar" queries as Django ORM requests individual queries to filter `incomes_this_month`, `expenses_this_month`, `incomes_previous_month` and `expenses_previous_month` by `date=` and `operation=` fields. I'm aware that `filter()` manager "resets" cached objects so I'm trying to find a more efficient way to get such a data withoud hitting a DB with extra queries.
I've attached DjDT query counter screenshot. Hope it makes the question more clear.

Appreciate any suggestion on this topic.

[image]

Comment: not gonna lie it's a bit complicated

Answer (score 0):

To reduce this to a single query you can use SQL's `GROUP_BY`, which lets us make a query for all incomes and expenses from this month and last month, and then separate them into the groups that we want. We can do this in Django by calling `.values()` on the queryset. The arguments given to `.values()` are the attributes that we want use to make different groups. In your case, we want to have different groups of data for different combinations of the month and operation of the transaction.

```py
transactions_all.values("month", "operation")
```

But before this query will work, we need to `.annotate()` the queryset so that the attribute "month" actually exists for each transaction. I don't know how your `transaction_filter.transaction_date_filter` works, so I'm going to write my own annotation. You might be able to adapt your existing date filter to fit this purpose. I'll use ExtractMonth to get just the month value from the `date_created` field.

```py
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractMonth

transactions_all.annotate(month=ExtractMonth("date_created"))
```

One problem with the annotated queryset right now is that the year of the transaction isn't considered at all, so we'd be getting all transactions made in this month of this year, but also this same month of last year and the year before (EVERY March instead of just this March). We can fix this by adding a filter to the queryset to make sure we're only querying data from the last two months.

```py
transactions_all.filter(date_created__range=[beginning_of_last_month, end_of_this_month])
```

The last thing to add to the queryset is a final `.annotate()` that will sum up the values of the transactions in each group. This `.annotate()` replaces the `.aggregate()` that you used in your queries, but serves the same purpose of summing the values of the transactions. We need to do this because our result has multiple objects, so we use `.annotate()` to add an attribute to each of the objects in the queryset. Using `.aggregate()` would compress the result of the queryset down to a single object, which would ruin the grouping that we did.

```py
transactions_all.filter(
        date_created__range=[beginning_of_last_month, end_of_this_month]
    ).annotate(
        month=ExtractMonth("date_created")
    ).values(
        "month", "operation"
    ).annotate(
        value_sum=Sum("value")
    )
```

This will get all the data that we need in a single SQL query, and give us output that looks like this:

```py
<QuerySet [
    {'operation': 'expenses', 'month': 2, 'value_sum': Decimal('750')},
    {'operation': 'expenses', 'month': 3, 'value_sum': Decimal('750')},
    {'operation': 'incomes', 'month': 2, 'value_sum': Decimal('240')},
    {'operation': 'incomes', 'month': 3, 'value_sum': Decimal('350')}
]>
```